# Trouble with GD, two images

Tags: php, image, gd

Why it doesn't work? If you separate the two parts of the code it works, but if it does not work together. The first part of the code is to take the sizes of the image, I have put a picture randomly. The second part is to make the other image depending on the size of the previous one.

```
<?php
$furni = imagecreatefrompng("http://www.bubblews.com/assets/images/news/234286842_1369263526.jpg");
$furnix = imagesx($furni);
$furniy = imagesy($furni);
if($furnix < 180){
    if($furniy < 180){
        $img = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);
    }else{
        $img = imagecreatetruecolor(200, ($furniy + 20));
    }
}else{
    if($furniy < 180){
        $img = imagecreatetruecolor(($furnix + 20), 200);
    }else{
        $img = imagecreatetruecolor(($furnix + 20), $furniy + 20));
    }
}
imagefill($img, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0));
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Define first and second parts.

Comment: you have extra `)` here `rniy + 20));` in 14th line

Comment: ...which should read as `$img = imagecreatetruecolor(($furnix + 20), $furniy + 20);`

Comment: Thanks! I've corrected all those errors.

Answer (score 0):

you have mistakes in your code

1) change `imagecreatefrompng` to `imagecreatefromjpeg`

2.)change `imagefill($img,` to `imagefill($furni,`

change same as above

`imagepng($img);` to `imagepng($furni);`

`imagedestroy($img);` to `imagedestroy($furni);`

Comment: Plus, did you read the comments under OP's question? You left out something.

Comment: Now show the image $furni but I don't want to show the image $furni, I want to take the size of this image and then create a new image with a black backgound depending on the size of the image $furni. By the way, my image is .png, sorry for the example.